# NullPointerException While Creating Session With Hibernate 4.3.10 FINAL

Tags: java, hibernate, session, nullpointerexception

I have created a simple Member Model Class and trying to retrieve all the members from the DB using Hibernate.
The **hibernate.cfg.xml** is as follows :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.112:1433;DatabaseName=WBSEDCL</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Asdf@123</property>  

    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>            
     <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>       

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="Member.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The Code For List members is as follows :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ArrayList<Member> listMembers(){
    Session sessionNew = null;
    ArrayList<Member> membrArray = new ArrayList<Member>();
    try{
          /* This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use */

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactoryNew = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
            sessionNew = sessionFactoryNew.openSession();

        String SQL_QUERY ="SELECT * FROM Member membr";
        Query query = sessionNew.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
            Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
            Member membr_obj = new Member((String)row[0],(String)row[1],(String)row[2],(String)row[3],(String)row[4],(String)row[5],(String)row[6],(String)row[7],
                    (String)row[8],(String)row[9],(String)row[10],(String)row[11],(String)row[12],(String)row[13],(String)row[14],(String)row[15],(String)row[16],(String)row[17],
                    (String)row[18],(String)row[19],(String)row[20],(String)row[21],(String)row[22],(String)row[23],(String)row[24],(String)row[25],(String)row[26],
                    (String)row[27],(String)row[28],(String)row[29],(String)row[30],(String)row[31],(String)row[32],(String)row[33],(String)row[34],(String)row[35],
                    (String)row[36],(String)row[37],(String)row[38],(String)row[39],(String)row[40],(String)row[41],(String)row[42],(String)row[43],
                    (String)row[44],(String)row[45],(String)row[46],(String)row[47],(String)row[48],(String)row[49],(String)row[50],(String)row[51],(String)row[52],(String)row[53]);

            membrArray.add(membr_obj);
        }
    }        
    catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println("Exception in listMember Function in PersistenceManager");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
    /* Actual contact insertion will happen at this step*/
        sessionNew.flush();
        sessionNew.close();
    }
    return membrArray;

}
```

Whenever the code is executed and the method is invoked by a calling function then a [nullpointerexception](/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception) is thrown at

> sessionNew.flush(); 
>   sessionNew.close();

Within The finally Block.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: means `sessionNew` is not initialised yet.

Comment: Maybe you are getting an exception so `sessionNew`is not being initialized.

Comment: post complete stacktrace of exception

Answer (score 0):

`sessionNew` is not initialized as you expect it to be. There seems to be an exception thrown either before its initialized or at the point of initializing it. The code should have run the catch block `sysout` statement after the exception is thrown. Since `Finally` block always run, it just gets executed calling `flush()` on a `null` object. Please check why `sessionNew` is not getting initialized. Try to debug and check it.

Comment: But why is that, `sessionNew = sessionFactoryNew.openSession();` is supposed to create the new session !!